# Typescript generic type parameter constrain to union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function

```
 uniqueIds(first: any[], second: any[]): number[] {
        let prop = first[0] instanceof Owner ? "OwnerId"
            : "BankId";
        return _.unique(
            _.map(
                first,
                o => o[prop]
            )
            .concat(
                _.map(
                    second,
                    o => o[prop]
                )
            )
        ).filter(o => o);
    }
```

Bank or Owner are the possible types I want this function to take, nothing else.  Bank and Owner share no interface or inheritance chain
Depending on the type passed in, I want to index into the object based on the property as seen in the first line inside the function.

What I have looks ugly, is there a way to to 
`uniqueIds<T> where T Bank | Owner` something like that without resorting to 
what I'm currently doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare:

```
function uniqueIds<T extends Owner[] | Bank[]>(first: T, second: T) { ... }
```

but you won't be able to prove to TypeScript that `o[prop]` is a number and you'll get a `noImplicitAny` error.  Assuming you know at each call site whether you are passing Owners or Banks, you may be better off passing in the property name, like this:

```
function uniqueIds<K extends string, T extends {[P in K]: number}>(
    prop: K, first: T[], second: T[]): number[] {
    return _.unique(
        _.map(
            first,
            o => o[prop]
        )
        .concat(
            _.map(
                second,
                o => o[prop]
            )
        )
    ).filter(o => o);
}
```